# SQLiteException: no such table Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Where I made mistake?

When I try to insert data into database, I get `Toast` message that I inserter,but in LOG file i see error:

> no such table: reservation (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO reservation(phone,address,surname,name,start,destination) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)

DBHelper.java

```
package com.example.demir.carsharing;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String TAG = DbHelper.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String DB_NAME = "carsharing.db";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String USER_TABLE = "users";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String COLUMN_PASS = "password";

    public static final String RES_TABLE="reservation";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME="name";
    public static final String COLUMN_SURNAME="surname";
    public static final String COLUMN_ADDRESS="address";
    public static final String COLUMN_PHONE="phone";
    public static final String COLUMN_START="start";
    public static final String COLUMN_DESTINATION="destination";


    /*
 create table users(
     id integer primary key autoincrement,
     email text,
     password text);
  */
    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_USERS = "CREATE TABLE " + USER_TABLE + "("
            + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_PASS + " TEXT);";

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_RESERVATION = "CREATE TABLE " + RES_TABLE + "("
            + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_SURNAME + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_ADDRESS + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_PHONE + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_START + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_DESTINATION + " TEXT);";


    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USERS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_RESERVATION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST" + USER_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST" + RES_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }


    public void addUser(String email, String password) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, email);
        values.put(COLUMN_PASS, password);

        long id = db.insert(USER_TABLE, null, values);
        db.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "user inserted" + id);
    }

    public boolean getUser(String email, String pass) {
        //HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String selectQuery = "select * from  " + USER_TABLE + " where " +
                COLUMN_EMAIL + " = " + "'" + email + "'" + " and " + COLUMN_PASS + " = " + "'" + pass + "'";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            return true;
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return false;
    }


    // method for  inserting data from method reservation
    public void addReservation(String name, String surname, String address, String phone, String start, String destination) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME, name);
        values.put(COLUMN_SURNAME, surname);
        values.put(COLUMN_ADDRESS, address);
        values.put(COLUMN_PHONE, phone);
        values.put(COLUMN_START, start);
        values.put(COLUMN_DESTINATION, destination);

        long a = db.insert(RES_TABLE, null, values);
        db.close();

        Log.e(TAG, "Data insetred" + a);
    }


    //Get data from Reservation
    public boolean getData(String name, String surname, String address, String phone, String start, String destination) {
        String query = "select * from  " + RES_TABLE + " where " +
                COLUMN_NAME + " = " + "'" + name + "'" + " , " + COLUMN_SURNAME + " = " + "'" + surname + "'" +
                COLUMN_ADDRESS + " = " + "'" + address + "'" + " , " + COLUMN_PHONE + " = " + "'" + phone + "'" +
                COLUMN_START + " = " + "'" + start + "'" + " , " + COLUMN_DESTINATION + " = " + "'" + destination + "'";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            return true;
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return false;
    }

    //insert data iinto Reservation
    public boolean insertReservation(String name, String surname, String address, String phone, String start, String destination) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("name",name);
        contentValues.put("surname",surname);
        contentValues.put("address",address);
        contentValues.put("phone",phone);
        contentValues.put("start",start);
        contentValues.put("destination",destination);
        db.insert("reservation",null,contentValues);
        return true;

    }
}
```

Reservation.java

```
package com.example.demir.carsharing;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static com.example.demir.carsharing.R.id.etName;

public class ReservationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button save;
    private EditText name, surname, address, phone, start, destination;
    private DbHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reservation);

        db = new DbHelper(this);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(etName);
        surname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSurname);
        address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAddress);
        phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
        start = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etStart);
        destination = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDestination);
        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        AddData();

    }

    public void AddData(){
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             boolean isInserted = db.insertReservation(name.getText().toString(),
                        surname.getText().toString(),
                        address.getText().toString(),
                        phone.getText().toString(),
                        start.getText().toString(),
                        destination.getText().toString());
                if(isInserted==true)
                    Toast.makeText(ReservationActivity.this,"Data inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else
                    Toast.makeText(ReservationActivity.this,"Data not inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you add the table later in your code? Uninstall your app to get rid of the old version of the database.

Comment: Yeah, first I create database and one table, after that I created secon tabe. Everything was good until I added second table, which is basically operatition ADD,UPDATE,DELET and in that moment application suck

Answer (score 0):

You might have made changes to your helper class after creating the tables for the first time, in which case you must clear your app's data before you rerun, in your device/emulator go to App Info and the Clear Data "for >= Marshmallow go to App Info -> Storage -> Clear Data" 
You don't have to delete and reinstall the whole app. that would be a waste of time.